# Saving a text file in Emeditor with a custom name using Javascript

Tags: emeditor

I want to save a document without popping up the "Save As" window. The name of the file document be specified before saving, how can I do that?

I know that there is a command called `document.Save( [ strName ] );` Sadly, it allows me to save the document with numbers only. I want to save the document with words (a,b,c,..) as well.

Comment: You should be able to pass a string. `document.Save("file.txt");` for example.